# ValueError: Cannot assign "'1'": "mymodel.provider" must be a "Providers" instance in django ,when save the crawled data to database using scrapy

Tags: django, django-models

when I save the crawl the data to the database using scrapy it shows an error like,

> self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name, ValueError: Cannot assign "'1'": "mymodel.provider" must be a  "Providers" instance

in django

spider.py

```
class CrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'example'
  start_urls = ['https://example.com/'
              ]

  def parse(self, response):
      items = crawlItem()

    all_section = response.css(' div.brief_box ')
    # all_sec = response.css('div._3WlLe')
    news_provider = '1'
    # for  quotes in all_sec:
    #     dec = quotes.css('._3WlLe::text').extract()
    for quote in all_section:

        title = quote.css('.posrel img').xpath("@alt").extract()
        details = quote.css('p a').xpath('text()').extract()
        image = quote.css('.posrel img').xpath("@data-src").extract()
        page_url = quote.css('p a').xpath("@href").extract()


        items['provider'] = provider
        items['title'] = title
        items['details'] = details
        items['image'] = image
        items['page_url'] = page_url
        yield items
```

item.py

```
from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem

from applications.crawl.models import Mymodel


class NewscrawlItem(DjangoItem):

  django_model = Mymodel
```

models.py

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    """
    model for storing news details
    """
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Providers, related_name='provider')
    details = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    page_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Providers(models.Model):
    provider = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    url = models.CharField("Website URL", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=REGIONS, null=True, blank=True)
    image = ImageField(upload_to='provider/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: items['provider'] = provider => items['provider_id'] = provider

Comment: removed irrelevant tags - the issue is purely about django models.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message clearly states, `MyModel.provider` should be a `Provider` instance, not the string representation of the related provider's pk. Either pass the Provider instance or, better, pass the pk but using the proper field name (would be `provider_id` in most cases but since your provider model's pk is named `provider` it *might* be `provider_provider` - but you just have to check your `YourModel` db schema to find out).